# Ошибка с сохранением данных в БД С#

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Привет не получается сохранить данные в БД. Использую SQLIte. Не может преобразовать из AppStaff в Staff

```
public partial class Staff : Window
{
    AppContecst db;
    public Staff()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new AppContecst(); //обращение к класу подключения базы данных выделение памяти
    }
    
    private void Button_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textboxName.Text.Trim();
        string famil = textboxfamil.Text.Trim();
        string otches = textboxotches.Text.Trim();
        string pol = textboxpol.Text.Trim();
        string podrazdel = textboxpodrazdel.Text.Trim();
        string dolzhnost = textboxdolzhnost.Text.Trim();
        string kabinet = textboxkabinet.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        string telefon_rab = textboxtelefon_rab.Text.Trim();
        string telefon_lichni = textboxtelefon_lichni.Text.Trim();
        string pochta = textboxpochta.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        string date_rozhde = textboxdate_rozhde.Text.Trim();
        string mesto_rozh = textboxmesto_rozh.Text.Trim();
        string grazhdan = textboxgrazhdan.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        string semeinoe = textboxsemeinoe.Text.Trim();
        MessageBox.Show("gut"); //окно с сообщением что регистрация прошла успешна
        AppStaff Staffs = new AppStaff(name, famil, otches, pol, podrazdel, dolzhnost, kabinet, telefon_rab, telefon_lichni, pochta, date_rozhde, mesto_rozh, grazhdan, semeinoe);
        db.Staffs.Add(Staffs);
        db.SaveChanges(); //Сохранение в базе данных

        AuthWindow authWindow = new AuthWindow();
        authWindow.Show();
        Hide();//Прятать текущее окно

    }
}
```

}

Вот класс из которого не может преобразовать

```
class AppStaff

{
    public int id { get; set; }
    private string name, famil, otches, pol, podrazdel, dolzhnost, kabinet, telefon_rab, telefon_lichni, pochta, date_rozhde, mesto_rozh, grazhdan, semeinoe;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public string Famil
    {
        get { return famil; }
        set { famil = value; }
    }
    public string Otches
    {
        get { return otches; }
        set { otches = value; }
    }
   public string Pol
    {
        get { return pol; }
        set { pol = value; }
    }
    public string Podrazdel
    {
        get { return podrazdel; }
        set { podrazdel = value; }
    }
    public string Dolzhnost
    {
        get { return dolzhnost; }
        set { dolzhnost = value; }
    }
    public string Kabinet
    {
        get { return kabinet; }
        set { kabinet = value; }
    }
    public string Telefon_rab
    {
        get { return telefon_rab; }
        set { telefon_rab = value; }
    }
    public string Telefon_lichni
    {
        get { return telefon_lichni; }
        set { telefon_lichni = value; }
    }
    public string Pochta
    {
        get { return pochta; }
        set { pochta = value; }
    }
    public string Date_rozhde
    {
        get { return date_rozhde; }
        set { date_rozhde = value; }
    }
    public string Mesto_rozh
    {
        get { return mesto_rozh; }
        set { mesto_rozh = value; }
    }
    public string Grazhdan
    {
        get { return grazhdan; }
        set { grazhdan = value; }
    }
    public string Semeinoe
    {
        get { return semeinoe; }
        set { semeinoe = value; }
    }
    public AppStaff() { }
    public AppStaff(string name, string famil, string otches , string pol, string podrazdel, string dolzhnost, string kabinet, string telefon_rab,
        string telefon_lichni, string pochta, string date_rozhde, string mesto_rozh, string grazhdan, string semeinoe)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.famil = famil;
        this.otches = otches;
        this.pol = pol;
        this.podrazdel = podrazdel;
        this.dolzhnost = dolzhnost;
        this.kabinet = kabinet;
        this.telefon_rab = telefon_rab;
        this.telefon_lichni = telefon_lichni;
        this.pochta = pochta;
        this.date_rozhde = date_rozhde;
        this.mesto_rozh = mesto_rozh;
        this.grazhdan = grazhdan;
        this.semeinoe = semeinoe;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ну, наверно у вас опечатка, по которой `db.Staff.Add()` ожидает тип `Staff` (то есть ваше окно).

Comment: Текст ошибки???

Comment: `Вот класс из которого не может преобразовать` - название класса потеряли

Comment: Текст ошибки который выдает SQLiteException: SQL logic error
no such table: AppStaffs

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях! Всю необходимую информацию выкладывайте в вопросе, отредактировав его. / У вас там лишние фигурные скобки затесались - удалите их. / Какое отношение к вопросу имеет XAML? / Какая ORM используется для работы с БД? Укажите *точную* версию.